# Possible to Recover From Deleting Forked Repo Deletion?

Tags: github, git-fork

I forked a large public repo and made a bunch of changes.  I made a pull request to that large repo that has had a lot of activity. Several people made github comments on those changes but my changes were not committed as far as I know to the main repo.  In the main repo, the changes are still showing but the say from "unknown repository".  I do have a clone of the repo that I deleted on my local.

Can the main repo I forked from still commit the changes even though I deleted my repo? Is it possible to put my repo back?  Am I SOL?

Clear the answer to the question "Am I Sure?" should have been no.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without looking the changes in question on the upstream repo (are they in an open pull request?), but based on what you've said the upstream repo should still be able to integrate your changes.

Comment: Yes @Chris.  They are in a public open repo and I can see the diff's int he comments. The "unknown repo" comment worries me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the main repo I forked from still commit the changes even though I deleted my repo?

Yes, they can.

Furthermore, the GitHub documentation [shows how users can even get the PR onto their local machine even if the fork from which it came is deleted](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally). This provides a way for other users to continue making changes to the PR if necessary before it is merged.

> Is it possible to put my repo back?

As I understand it you can re-fork the repository but this will not result in your PR being "reattached". I am not aware of any way to make this happen.

Of course, you could delete the PR and create another one. Whether that's worthwhile is up to you and the maintainers of the upstream repository. Personally, I wouldn't bother.